# reading CSV file with datetime column giving weird result

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have one weird issue reading `datetime` value from CSV file. When I read the file programmically, it reads the value of `datetime` column as shown in below image.

As you can see in below image, it is just like some number eg `57.07.7` (**NOTE**: I can't change the cell format of the CSV file)

**You can download file from here: https://easyupload.io/u1r8rc**

[image]

**BUT**

same file, if you open in `notepad` or `notepad++`, it gives proper `datetime` value as shown in below image

[image]

When I read as below, it is giving me result as first image,

```
const xlsx = require("xlsx");

const result = // read file here and get buffer data;

const file = xlsx.read(result);

const sheetNames = file.SheetNames;
const totalSheets = sheetNames.length;


// Loop through sheets
for (let i = 0; i < totalSheets; i++) {
      // Convert to json using xlsx
      let tempData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheetNames[i]]);
      
      parsedData.push(...tempData);
```

}

If I `console.log(parseData)`, it shows some `number` not `date(as string)`.

What's wrong? How can I read proper date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `cellDates:true` to parse dates [as type d](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#data-types)

try this:

```
const file = xlsx.read(result, {cellDates:true});
```

..or maybe use a csv parser..